# The sum of column times row vector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the $n \times n$ matrix $A = \Sigma_{i=1}^r d_i a_i a_i'$, expressed in terms of $r$ $n \times 1$ orthogonal vectors $a_1,...,a_r$ and some non-zero scalars $d_1,...,d_r$, where $r \leq n$, is of rank $r$.

I know this looks simple. But I cannot give a rigorous proof. I know individual column times row vector matrix is rank $1$.

Comment: Note that $A a_k = d_k \|a\|_k^2 a_k$. Hence $a_1,...,a_r$ are in the range of $A$.

Comment: (Conversely the range of $A$ is in $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_r\rangle$. Consider what $a_i'x$ is.)

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. Following your hint: the dimension of column space of A is at least r. So I can show rank(A) $ \geq r$. How to show the other direction?

Comment: You need to do a little work. For any $x$ you have $Ax = \sum_k d_k (a_k^Tx) a_k$. Can you show that this means that $Ax$ lies in the span of $a_1,...,a_r$?